# MXNET CMake reports "GPU support is disabled"

Tags: cmake, gpu, mxnet

I am trying to build money from source in a GPU-enabled machine. I have a NVIDIA P 100 GPU.  When I build MXNET using `make`, it reports that:

The snippet from CMake log is given below

```
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 10.2.89
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin/nvcc
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin/nvcc -- works
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done

-- GPU support is disabled
```

I want to build it with GPU support. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When building MXNet from source, the message `GPU support is disabled` in the output of CMake is a bit confusing. This specific message has nothing to do with CUDA. It is actually generated if we try to enable Intel MKL DNN support (`-DUSE_MKLDNN=1`) and the Intel OpenCL runtime is not installed in the system ( see the [`CMake file`](https://github.com/intel/mkl-dnn/blob/cb2cc7ac17ff4e2ef50805c7048d33256d82be4d/cmake/OpenCL.cmake) in which it is printed ). CMake tries to look for Intel OpenCL runtime and throws this message if not found. I believe the OpenCL runtime enables GPU support for Intel's GPUs ( `Intel HD Graphics`, `Intel Iris` and `Intel Iris Pro` ).

Don't worry about this error message if you do not intend to use Intel Graphics support. It won't affect the CUDA support for MXNet. If you want to suppress this message, then disable MKL DNN support (`-DUSE_MKLDNN=0`). If you care about Intel Graphics too, then install [Intel OpenCL Runtime](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers).